# How to like visual studio debug diagnostic to get process Maximum memory usage for method

Tags: c#, .net

Like visual studio debug diagnostic tools, it can know `max memory usage`  by chart
[image]

I've tried [dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) `MemoryDiagnoser` to get `Allocated`, but it's `all memory usage` not max memory usage.
And test below code to get max memory usage

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";

        long maxMemoryUsage = 0;

        process.Start();

        while (!process.HasExited)
        {
            process.Refresh();
            maxMemoryUsage = Math.Max(maxMemoryUsage, process.PagedMemorySize64);
        }

        Console.Out.WriteLine("Memory used: " + (maxMemoryUsage / 1024.0) / 1024.0 + "MB");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: This tool doesn't become useful until you use a lot of memory.  17MB is peanuts.

Comment: @HansPassant it's example, actually over 2GB~800GB